# Unable to run a simple android application

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to Android. I modified the activity_main.xml as described in this link. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

When I try to run, AVD says, unfortunately your app has stopped working.

I tried to change minimumsdk and targetsdk version in the manifestfile but that didn't help.

```
02-01 12:01:25.964: W/Trace(771): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-01 12:01:25.993: W/Trace(771): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-01 12:01:26.513: D/AndroidRuntime(771): Shutting down VM
02-01 12:01:26.513: W/dalvikvm(771): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstdevapp/com.example.firstdevapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class editText
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class editText
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.example.firstdevapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  ... 11 more
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.editText" on path: /data/app/com.example.firstdevapp-2.apk
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  ... 21 more
02-01 12:01:29.062: I/Process(771): Sending signal. PID: 771 SIG: 9
```

Can anyone help me find out the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant line with the root cause is this one:

```
02-01 12:01:26.523: E/AndroidRuntime(771): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.editText" on path: /data/app/com.example.firstdevapp-2.apk
```

I would expect that in your layout, you've failed to capitalize your "e", putting in `editText` instead of `EditText`.

Comment: That is a silly mistake. Didn't realize about the capitalization of E and B in Button. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without your code, but from the line `error inflating class editText` I would guess that you forgot to capitalise the E in your `<EditText` in your XML layout

Comment: Not showing the rest of my scentance for some reason, anyways.... in a <EditText in your XML layout

Comment: You need to properly format it as code (I've fixed it). Without the code formatting, the site thinks you're trying to add unsupported HTML and stripping it.